# Sentence structure - as much/many (as)

Tags: sentence-construction

Here's a sentence written in my book.

> Sometimes these nights can go on and on well after midnight. I think I won't be able to attend **as many of them after I'm married.**

I think some phrase has been omitted, so is it correct to phrase it like the following sentence?

> Sometimes these nights can go on and on well after midnight. I think I won't be able to attend **as many of them after I'm married as I attend now.**

Comment: What does this have to do with your title?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an omitted word: *of*.

Sometimes these nights can go on and on well after midnight. I think I won't be able to attend as many **of** them after I'm married.

Also, the second sentence is acceptable if you add the *of*; however, the phrase "as I attend now" is somewhat redundant. It's implied by the context of the sentence that the speaker is comparing how often he will be able to attend in the future (after marriage) with how often he attends currently.

Comment: Would it also be acceptable to remove `"them"`, e.g. `"I think I won't be able to attend as many after I'm married."`?

Comment: @BCdotWEB yes.  "won't be able to attend as many" and "won't be able to attend as many of them" are both correct.